# How to integrate Git and TFS across a VPN?

Tags: git, tfs

We have a quite interesting situation. Two developing teams, belonging to two different companies.

- Company A (the *client*) uses their own TFS server in their own internal network - they use it not just to maintain their codebase but for bug tracking and so on.
- Company B (*our dev team*) uses the same TFS through a VPN connection.

Company A policies do not allow the creation of branches off of **main**, so, at Company B we were thinking of:

- starting to use **git** on each of our developer's machine,
- each developer would be able to create his/her own local branches,
- developers would commit those changes to a central git repo on a Company B server
- somehow those changes in our git would be merged into the **main** branch of Company A's TFS server.

Is this feasible? Can you suggest a more proven/solid solution to solve this problem? Is adding git to the table just asking for more trouble than it needs to be? Would it be better to just have our own TFS and then somehow keep our TFS in sync with theirs - especially when we consider the fact that the two companies work on very different projects, **never** on the same files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git-TF to clone a TFVC repository and work with it within Git. I have a blob post that you can use to get most of the commands:

- http://nakedalm.com/migrating-source-code-with-history-to-tfs-2012-with-git-tf/

If you have TFS locally and create a Team Project that supports Git repositories instead of TFVC you can have everything. Your developers can work on TFS as if it was the only one, then when you are ready you can craft a commit to the remote TFS over vpn.

You could make things easyer by using VSO (http://tfs.visualstudio.com) and have the other company do a pull(with a script that you give them) any time it is required.